# jquery tablesorter - sorting number with space

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i have problem with jQuery tablesorter and numbers like 12 345 678,91

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        id: 'thousands',
        is: function(s) { 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) {
            return s.replace(' ','').replace(/,/g,'');
        }, 
        type: 'numeric' 
    }); 

    $("#tablesorter").tablesorter({
    headers: { 
                3: { sorter:'thousands' }, 
                4: { sorter:'thousands' }, 
                5: { sorter:'thousands' } 
            }
    });
});
```

output filter:

```
-1 295,76
-331,2
-330,01
-290
0
3 986 495,06
1 942 503,09
0
0
```

When i replace this: s.replace(' ','').replace(/,/g,'');
by this : s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9/A-Za-z. ]/g),"");
...even worse than it was.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parser isn't replacing all of the spaces; using `replace(' ','')` will only replace the first space. Also, the comma should be replaced with a decimal point since it indicates a fraction. So, try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/367/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'thousands',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return s.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer converts spaces to `&nbsp;`.
For me works this:

```
return s.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Triple_6:

Understand the meaning before implementing the solution:
My guess is you don't want spaces or ,  or anything just pure numbers.

The expression below means replace everything other than numbers, alphabets,a decimal point and space with "".

```
s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9/A-Za-z. ]/g),"");
```

The above was suggested by me.

**Solution:**

If you dont want spaces then remove that from the expression.

```
s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9/A-Za-z.]/g),"");
```

If you want to have the sign then include that

```
s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9/A-Za-z.+-]/g),"");
```

**Meaning of the Regex expression:**
new RegExp(/[Except this list]/g)," replace everything with this");

Working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rK5s4/1/

Next time do make it a point to mention that you would like multiple occurrences of something removed. It is not clear from your question.

Also try putting them through jsfiddle before incorporating it.